# Angular 4 - How to send value of latitude and longitude to API

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-google-maps

I have a problem using AGM (Angular Google Maps), AGM version is not compatible with angular v4.3. When i updated AGM new version, it makes my code (Angular) have a lot of problem (code error). I have been trying to find another solution to solve Google Maps problem in Angular.

Do you have any idea or solution for Google Maps that compatible with Angular 4.3 ?
From Google Maps i need to search places and fetch longitude and latitude.

Comment: sounds like you are in versioning hell. I would try to use older versions of AGM until you find something that works (I am using `@agm/core: 1.0.0-beta.2` and `@types/googlemaps: 3.29.2` in angular 5)

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API is a JavaScript API and can be used in an Angular 4.3 application as in any other.

Take a look at their docs:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

You will need to register and have a key to use it, like any other google API.